# Python Selenium Firefox Won't Open On Line XML File

Tags: python, selenium

I'm making a call with Selenium using the Firefox Geckodriver to the Edgar Website with a url I manually created and Firefox won't open it.

When I manually try to open the file - I get a prompt from Firefox asking me how I want to view it and what program I want to I want to view it with.

Here is my code:

Creating the URL:

```
def create_url(param_dict, endpoint):

    param_dict_keys = list(param_dict.keys())
    url = (endpoint + "?" +
       param_dict_keys[0] + "=" + param_dict['action'] + "&" +
       param_dict_keys[1] + "=" + param_dict['CIK'] + "&" +
       param_dict_keys[2] + "=" + param_dict['type'] + "&" +
       param_dict_keys[3] + "=" + param_dict['datea'] + "&" +
       param_dict_keys[4] + "=" + param_dict['owner'] + "&" +
       param_dict_keys[5] + "=" + param_dict['start'] + "&" +
       param_dict_keys[6] + "=" + param_dict['output'] + "&" +
       param_dict_keys[7] + "=" + param_dict['count'] )

    return url

#define endpoint

endpoint = r"https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar"

#define our parameters

param_dict = {'action':'getcompany',
              'CIK': 'AAPL',
              'type':'8-K',
              'datea':'20070101',
              'owner':'exclude',
              'start':'',
              'output':'atom',
              'count':'100'}

search_url = create_url(param_dict,endpoint)
```

Then I initialize the webdriver and call the url:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'geckodriver.exe')
driver.get(search_url)
```

Firefox opens but I get the following prompt:

[image]

I have also tried:

```
driver.navigate().to(search_url)
```

But I get a separate error that webdriver does not have a function navigate.

I have checked the url and it has been created properly.  I manually paste it (removing the quotes on either side of the url string) and it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Guidance appreciated.

Comment: The Content-Type of the response is `Content-Type: application/atom+xml`. This content type is not supported by default by FireFox (and neither do Chrome).

Answer (score 1):

Quoting this [article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/feed-reader-replacements-firefox):

> Firefox's built-in support for web feeds and Live Bookmarks was
>   removed with the release of Firefox version 64 in December 2018.
>
> After reviewing the usage data and technical maintenance requirements
>   for these features and taking into account alternative RSS/Atom feed
>   readers already available to you, we have realized that these features
>   have an outsized maintenance and security impact relative to their
>   usage. Removing the feed reader and Live Bookmarks allows us to focus
>   on features that make a greater impact.

You can install an add-on to read Atom RSS files.

Comment: Would I have to install the add in in the browser opening it manually.  Then when Selenium calls it it will work?